# How can I get originalvalues from EF savechanges for complex primary key

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, logging, audit

i've implemented audit log for all my db objects but i'm running into an issue because of a special case.
i have code similar to the following.

```
 private IEnumerable<CDMA_CHANGE_LOG> GetAuditRecords(DbEntityEntry ent, string userId, string primaryKeyId, bool updateFlag, object originalEntity)
    {
        List<CDMA_CHANGE_LOG> result = new List<CDMA_CHANGE_LOG>();
        string changeId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        TableAttribute tableAttr = ent.Entity.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TableAttribute), false).SingleOrDefault() as TableAttribute;
        // Get table name (if it has a Table attribute, use that, otherwise get the pluralized name)
        string entityName = tableAttr != null ? tableAttr.Name : ObjectContext.GetObjectType(ent.Entity.GetType()).Name;
        var changeTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
        if (ent.State == EntityState.Modified)
        {

            foreach (var prop in ent.OriginalValues.PropertyNames)
            {                    
                 //we cant use this because getdatabasevalues will error out when there are 2 rows in the db for this primarykey (U,A)
                //var originalValue = ent.GetDatabaseValues().GetValue<object>(prop) == null ? "" : ent.GetDatabaseValues().GetValue<object>(prop).ToString();
                var currentValue = ent.CurrentValues[prop] == null ? "" : ent.CurrentValues[prop].ToString();
                // For updates, we only want to capture the columns that actually changed
                var primaryKey = GetPrimaryKeyValue(ent);
                if (originalValue != currentValue)
                {
                    result.Add(new CDMA_CHANGE_LOG()
                    {
                        USERID = userId,
                        DATECHANGED = changeTime,
                        EVENTTYPE = "M",    // Modified
                        ENTITYNAME = entityName,
                        PRIMARYKEYVALUE = primaryKey.ToString(),
                        PROPERTYNAME = prop,
                        OLDVALUE = originalValue,
                        NEWVALUE = currentValue,
                        CHANGEID = changeId
                    });
                }
            }

        }
        return result;
    }
```

now i cant use originalValue = ent.GetDatabaseValues().GetValue(prop) because the records have two fields as primary key so i thought i could query the original value manually from the controller and send as

```
object originalEntity
```

so i'm wondering how do i cast originalEntity to the current entity

```
var originalValues = Convert.ChangeType(originalEntity, ent.GetType());
```

does not work.
i'm finding it difficult to get. thanks for any help.

Comment: You could give a try to [Audit.NET](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET#auditnet)'s [EntityFramework extension](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/master/src/Audit.EntityFramework/README.md#auditentityframework), it will automatically audit the changes. Or take a look at its code where it [gets the column values](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/master/src/Audit.EntityFramework/DbContextHelper.Net45.cs#L23), or where it [gets the primary key values](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/master/src/Audit.EntityFramework/EntityKeyHelper.cs#L154)